# Как найти нужный элемент в List<List<string>>()?

Tags: c#

Необходимо найти данное слово. В одном списке содержатся строки таблицы, в другом-эти строки. Как можно это осуществить?(использовать двумерный ToList обязательно)

Answer (score 1):

```
var lists = new List<List<string>> {
    new List<string> { "X", "Y", "Z" },
    new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" }
};

if (lists.SelectMany(i => i).Contains("B"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Элемент найден");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Элемент не найден");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var lists = new List<List<string>> {
    new List<string> {
        "X", "Y", "Z"
    },
    new List<string> {
        "X", "Y", "Z"
    }       
};

foreach (var list in lists) {
    foreach (var item in list) {
        if (item == "X") {
            Console.WriteLine("Нашли!");
        }
    }
}
```